# Apply batch OCR through command line

Tags: batch-file, ocr

I am totally new to batch scripting for cmd (Windows).
I have installed tesseract to work as a command line OCR tool.

Now I would like to run OCR on 100 images that I have stored in a folder.
How can I do it with batch ?

The command to run tesseract on an image and return the OCR text in a text file is:

```
"C:\OCR\tesseract" "C:\Image_to_OCR.jpg" "C:\out"
```

More information: http://chillyfacts.com/convert-image-to-text-using-cmd-prompt/

As you can see, I would probably need to make a for loop whith automatically iterates through the number of pictures and changes the name of the picture in the command accordingly and of course also the output name of the text file... but I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be very appreciated !

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the answer by Stephan, I could write:

```
for %%A in (C:\*.jpg) do "C:\OCR\tesseract.exe" "%%~fA" "C:\out"
```

However, the command line (cmd) only apears quickly and closes imidiatley and nothing happens.

My files are not directly in C:\ but in "C:\Users\James\Desktop\", therefore I wrote the command as such:

```
for %%A in (C:\Users\James\Desktop\*.jpg) do "C:\OCR\tesseract.exe" "%%~fA" "C:\out"
```

...but as said before, it does not work somehow.

Also, can I change the output txt name to be the same as the input image name, like so ?

```
for %%A in (C:\Users\James\Desktop\*.jpg) do "C:\OCR\tesseract.exe" "%%~fA" "%%~fA"
```

**This worked :**

I got two great answers! Thanks a lot. The final thing that worked was a mix between both answers:

```
@Echo off
PushD C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR || (Echo couldn't pushd C:\OCR & Exit /B 1)
for %%A in ("C:\Users\EPFL\Google Drive\EDx PDF Maker\Cellular Mechanisms of Brain Functions\Slides\1\*.jpg") do tesseract.exe "%%~fA" "%%~dpnxA"
```

Comment: You could use a loop, running multiple `tesseract imagename  …` commands or alternatively create a listing of the files and run a single `tesseract imagelist …` against it. Please search the site to learn how to use `For` for the looping method, or `For`, `Dir` or `Where` to create an imagelist. In the meantime, entering those commands at the Command Prompt, followed by the `/?` option should provide you with their usage information, `For /?`, `Dir /?` and `Where /?`.

Comment: This should help https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html

Comment: @Compo Thank you very much. Two questions: How would you create an imagelist ? and how do you change the name of the image file in every loop operation ?

Comment: @james, once you've read/understood the method you've decided upon, it is expected that you create a [mcve] of the code and a properly formed question based on [ask], then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51502352/edit) to reflect what you've learned.

Comment: @Compo I understand. Well, thanks to Stephan I have added a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code. Maybe you know why it does not work ?

Comment: Are you sure you can write to the top-level directory on C: ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your program `C:\OCR\tesseract.exe` but I assume it needs supporting tools/files present in the `C:\OCR` folder, so either you have to set that folder as the current one or have it contained in your path variable.

```
@Echo off
PushD "C:\OCR" || (Echo couldn't pushd C:\OCR & Exit /B 1)
for %%A in ("C:\Users\James\Desktop\*.jpg") do tesseract.exe "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA.txt"
```

The `"%%~dpnA.txt"` will save the text with same drive/path/filename and extension `.txt`

Comment: Thanks a lot !  We are getting closer. I now get the error: 

Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.02 with Leptonica
Error in fopenReadStream: file not found
Error in findFileFormat: image file not found

Comment: I think that I understand the error . I see the error... the folder of the images has a name which is composed of two words without underscore, like "this folder"

Comment: Taking a quick look it  seems that the extension `.txt` is appended automatically, so no need to express it. As for the folder with spaces, enclose it in double quotes in the for command: `or %%A in ("C:\Users\James\Desktop\*.jpg") do tesseract.exe "%%~fA" "%%~dpn.txt"`

Comment: With "%%~dpnxA" at the end instead of "%%~dpn.txt" it worked ! :)

Comment: Shame on me - forgot to append the meta variable, good catch.

Comment: No worries ! Thanks a lot ! Small question: If I want to make the batch file "mobile", meaning that it will do OCR to all jpg files which are in the same folder, how can I do it... I was thinking of something like set: mypath=%cd%
%mypath% but then I don't know how to in cooperate it

Comment: It should already process all files in `"C:\Users\James\Desktop\*.jpg"`. To have it more versatile you could pass in a command line argument to the batch and reference it with `"%~1"`

Comment: I mean that if I use this batch on another computer, the path will be different, but I don't really want to manually edit the path of the folder containing the pictures. I would like to simply place the batch file there and press go...

Comment: Understood, but you'll need to have `tesseract` installed on every computer. That path will always be `C:\OCR`? Otherwise to address all pictures in the same folder as the batch resdes in, use: `For %%A in ("%~f0\*.jpg") do tesseract.exe "%%~fA" "%%~dpn.txt"`

Comment: Yes,tesseract is always installed at the same location. Hmm... ("%~f0\*.jpg") does does not seem to work and I think that at the end one needs to write "%%~dpnxA"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176672/discussion-between-lotpings-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over the files:

```
for %%A in (C:\*.jpg) do "C:\OCR\tesseract.exe" "%%~fA" "C:\out"
```

`%%A` is the filenames (one at each run of the loop),
`%%~fA` is the fully qualified filename (just to be sure).

Read the output of `for /?` to learn more about those modifiers.

Note: this is batchfile syntax. To use it directly on command line, replace every `%%` with a single `%`

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, it does not work. Please see my updated question.

Comment: not sure, how exactly `tesseract` works. From the documentation I assume the output file is your input `C:\out` plus `.txt`), so `C:\out.txt`. Is that correct? If yes, try `%%~dpnxA` (**D**rive, **P**ath, **N**ame (without extension)). `%%~fA` would be D,P,N, as above plus **E**xtension.

Comment: Almost works ! But I see the error... the folder of the images has a name which is composed of two words without underscore, like "this folder". Is there a method to include such names ?

Comment: That doesn't look like a `cmd` error. Must come from tesseract. If it doesn't like spaces, there is nothing you can do except renaming.